# Filling pandas dataframe with uneven numpy array, vertically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a numpy array where the size of every entry is the index of that entry, i.e. [ [A], [B, C], [D, E, F] ]. I want to make a pandas Dataframe on this which would look as follows:

```
A    B    D
     C    E
          F
```

So it would have to fill the data vertically. However, it only fills in the following order.

```
A
B    C
D    E    F
```

I have tried various ways to transpose the data, but I just cannot find a way that works.

Comment: how about `pd.DataFrame(your_array).T` ?

Comment: Could you describe your original array in more detail? Could it be that the entries in your array are lists? You can't have a 2D array with different number of elements. That's why `np.array([['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']])` will give a 1D array with list, not a 2D array.

Comment: @anky Thank you this works!

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the error will be shown as that of inhomogenity as your elements to be put in a row are not the same. In case you want to put out blanks, you have to mention that as a blank. For example:

```
np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "", "F", "", ""]).reshape(3, 3)
np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "", "F", "", ""]).reshape(3, 3, order="F")
```